# Microsoft JDBC and Datetime2 - rounding issue

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

From our application we create a java.sql.Timestamp like this:

```
Timestamp currentTimeStamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
currentTimeStamp.setNanos((int) (System.nanoTime() % 1000000000));
```

And then use this as column value in a distributed transaction against a DB2 and MSSQL.

DB2 strips off the digits it cannot use and stores the remaining.

MSSQL rounds the digits and stores the value.

The problem then becomes that the timestamp value is different in the two databases even though they both have the same fraction digits of 6.

Example reproduced using pure T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(x DATETIME2(6)) 
INSERT @t SELECT '2017-03-28 14:00:59.4106489'
SELECT x FROM @t
```

Result:
2017-03-28 14:00:59.410649

Expected:
2017-03-28 14:00:59.410648

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to create a `Timestamp` value that SQL Server won't round, thereby ensuring that the values will be the same in both databases. One approach would be to use a utility function like

```java
private static Timestamp truncatedTimestamp(Timestamp ts, int precision) {
    return Timestamp.valueOf(ts.toString().substring(0, precision + 20));
}
```

to truncate the `Timestamp` value at the specified `precision` (6, in your case).

Comment: I have thought of that, but it is very error prone based on the developers. 

I'd rather ensure the database handles this correctly than tell a team of 20 developers to remember to use X precision when writing to datetime2(x) columns. This also allows the DBA and the developer role to stay split

Also AFAIK most databases do not round values, they instead either trim it or throw an error.

Answer (score -1):

The issue that MSSQL Character length is 19 positions minimum to 23 maximum
because of that it rounded it to be at maximum 23 Character 
This is the case

Comment: Sorry, but the 23-character maximum applies to [datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql), not [datetime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql).